# Droping a range of rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to clear the first 9 rows of a dataframe in Pandas.

I have to drop all rows using:

```py
df.drop([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? 
I have tried using a range:

`df.drop([0:9])`

but this does not help.

Comment: `df.iloc[9:]`...

Comment: You can do `df.drop(range(9))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is by indexing: `df.drop(df.index[0:9])`. This example will drop the first ten rows.